# C# percent calculation with decimal type causes problems

Tags: c#, math, decimal, percentage

```
decimal hundred = 100;
decimal value = 5000;
decimal sum = 1100000;

decimal valuePercentOfSum = value / sum * hundred;        //result = 0.4545454545454545454545454500M
decimal percentOfSum = sum / hundred * valuePercentOfSum; //result = 4999.9999999999999999999999500M
```

I would expect the result of `percentOfSum` to be the original value of *value* (5000)

I need a way to do calculations like this back and forth, and I can simply not do ANY rounding.

Any help?

Comment: Use rationals rather than fixed point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone has to *Round* (whether you like it or not), as you're dealing with *Irrational Numbers* and/or *Numeric Types* with a limited precision

If you use `double` it will *Round* for you, if you use `decimal` it has more precision. However, you will have to live with the fact it leaves the precision it has.

Depending on what you want to do, a `decimal` might be less convenient, though if you understand the ramifications for both *Types* (and that there is no free lunch), you can choose accordingly.

Comment: Really sad to hear this, becuase I dislike using double here since that has caused other problems for me earlier, such as 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.300000004

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen unfortunately for ultimate accuracy and convenience, you have to trade something. It really depends on what you want to do and why to determine which might be the best approach and most convenient .

Answer (score 1):

If you use double instead of decimal you should get better results.

```
double hundred = 100;
double value = 5000;
double sum = 1100000;

double valuePercentOfSum = value / sum * hundred; 
double percentOfSum = sum / hundred * valuePercentOfSum; // result = 5000
```

Comment: I guess, **Double increases accuracy** is partially true, because decimal is used to get perfect results rather then double